# Why is xcopy claiming this is a recursive error and not copying the target file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My goal: I am wanting to create a batch file that will make a folder, whose name is given to it from an array, and then copy a file from the working directory into that newly created folder.

My problem: I can create the folders, but the xcopy is giving me a recursive copy error. It is then not copying the file.

Previous attempts: After looking at other questions, I gather it's because I'm copying from the a parent folder of the eventual target folder? Is this understanding correct? I've also tried different ways of stating the folder name, but to no avail.

Any help as to the quickest workaround or solution would be appreciated.

```
::This is where eventually all folder names will go.
set fruits[0]=apple
set fruits[1]=pear
set fruits[2]=plum
set /A n=0

echo Current directory is %cd%
echo[
:SymLoop 

if defined fruits[%n%] ( 
   call echo Array is set to %%fruits[%n%]%%
   echo Now making dir.
   call md %%fruits[%n%]%%  
   call xcopy /s "H:\HomeFolder\copiedFile.xls" "H:\HomeFolder\%%fruits[%n%]%%"
   set /a "n+=1"
   echo[
   GOTO :SymLoop 
)

echo program ended...
```

This is the portion of the output with the error,

```
Array is set to apple
Now making dir.
Cannot perform a cyclic copy
0 File(s) copied

Array is set to pear
Now making dir
Cannot perform a cyclic copy
0 File(s) copied

Array is set to plum
Now making dir.
Cannot perform a cyclic copy
0 File(s) copied
```

Comment: Please supply the exact text of the error you are receiving.

Comment: In this command: `call xcopy /s "H:\HomeFolder\copiedFile.xls" "H:\HomeFolder\%%fruits[%n%]%%"` the `/s` switch specify "copy files _and subfolders_ from H:\HomeFolder folder", but the new `%%fruits[%n%]%%` folder is _also_ inside such a folder, so this is a "recursive error". If you want to copy just one file, remove the `/s` switch...

Comment: I just amended initial post. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: @Aacini Thank you! That worked! I assumed the /s wouldn't matter because I was copying an individual file and not a folder. I feel dumb it was such an easy fix. Thanks again.